# ruby on rails linux error in starting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, web

I have a problem when I try to install ruby on rails on linux ubuntu latest version.

Ruby version: ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version: 6.0.3.2
i have nodejs and mysql

When I am in the folder of my project and I launch the command: Rails server
Here is the error I get:

```
tchoune@tchounePc:~/ruby/myapp$ rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    77: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    76: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    75: from /home/tchoune/ruby/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    74: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    73: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    72: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    71: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    70: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    69: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    68: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    67: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    66: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    65: from /home/tchoune/ruby/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    64: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    63: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    62: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    61: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    60: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    59: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    58: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    57: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    56: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    55: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    54: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    53: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    52: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    51: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    50: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    49: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    48: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    47: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    46: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    45: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    44: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    43: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    42: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    41: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    40: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    39: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    38: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    37: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
    36: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    35: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    34: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    33: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    32: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    31: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    30: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    29: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    28: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    27: from /home/tchoune/ruby/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    26: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    25: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    24: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    23: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    22: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    21: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    20: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    19: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    18: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    17: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    16: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    15: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    14: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    13: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    12: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    11: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker.rb:35:in `bootstrap'
    10: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:25:in `bootstrap'
     9: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
     8: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:83:in `load'
     7: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:51:in `public_manifest_path'
     6: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:47:in `public_output_path'
     5: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:43:in `public_path'
     4: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:84:in `fetch'
     3: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:88:in `data'
     2: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `load'
     1: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `read'
/home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/tchoune/ruby/myapp/config/webpacker.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    76: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    75: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    74: from /home/tchoune/ruby/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    73: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    72: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    71: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    70: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    69: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    68: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    67: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    66: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    65: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    64: from /home/tchoune/ruby/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    63: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    62: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    61: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    60: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    59: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    58: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    57: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    56: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    55: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    54: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    53: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    52: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    51: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    50: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    49: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    48: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    47: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    46: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    45: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    44: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    43: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    42: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    41: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    40: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    39: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    38: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    37: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    36: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
    35: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    34: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    33: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    32: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    31: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    30: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    29: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    28: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    27: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    26: from /home/tchoune/ruby/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    25: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    24: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    23: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    22: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    21: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    20: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    19: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    18: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    17: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    16: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    15: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    14: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    13: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    12: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    11: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    10: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker.rb:35:in `bootstrap'
     9: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:25:in `bootstrap'
     8: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
     7: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:83:in `load'
     6: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:51:in `public_manifest_path'
     5: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:47:in `public_output_path'
     4: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:43:in `public_path'
     3: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:84:in `fetch'
     2: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:88:in `data'
     1: from /home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:91:in `load'
/home/tchoune/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:95:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found /home/tchoune/ruby/myapp/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/tchoune/ruby/myapp/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
```

Does anyone know what configuration I am missing?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Did you try running `rails webpacker:install` ?

Comment: Yes he need to install Yarn, but i have..

Comment: @Tchoune Looks like your js setup isn't ready. Can you share your node version: `node -v` ? Are you using nvm for node version managing ?

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli Thanks for reply. I have node V12.18.2  with rbenv

Answer (score 0):

@viktor Yes he need to install Yarn, but i have..

```
tchoune@tchounePc:~/ruby/myapp$ rails webpacker:install
Yarn not installed. Please download and install Yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
tchoune@tchounePc:~/ruby/myapp$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
[sudo] Mot de passe de tchoune : 
Atteint :1 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Réception de :2 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]                                                                        
Atteint :3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                             
Atteint :4 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                                  
Réception de :5 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]                                                                     
Atteint :6 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                   
Atteint :7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                               
Réception de :8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]                                                  
Atteint :9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                 
Réception de :10 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [240 kB]                        
Réception de :11 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [125 kB]                         
Réception de :12 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [165 kB] 
Réception de :13 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [41.4 kB]                                   
Atteint :14 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x focal InRelease                             
Réception de :15 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [58.7 kB]
Réception de :16 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [7’284 B]
Réception de :17 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [67.1 kB]
Réception de :18 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [126 kB]
Réception de :19 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [173 kB]
Réception de :20 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [87.5 kB]
Réception de :21 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [1’640 B]
Réception de :22 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [3’988 B]
Réception de :23 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2’468 B]
Réception de :24 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1’972 B]
Réception de :25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [129 kB]
Réception de :26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [46.2 kB]
Réception de :27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [21.2 kB]
Réception de :28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [13.0 kB]
Réception de :29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [37.3 kB]
Réception de :30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [35.8 kB]
Réception de :31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1’732 B]
1’702 ko réceptionnés en 2s (921 ko/s)                                           
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
7 paquets peuvent être mis à jour. Exécutez « apt list --upgradable » pour les voir.
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
yarn est déjà la version la plus récente (1.22.4-1).
Les paquets suivants ont été installés automatiquement et ne sont plus nécessaires :
  fonts-lato javascript-common libc-ares2 libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libjs-jquery libllvm9 libllvm9:i386 linux-headers-5.4.0-26
  linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic nodejs-doc python3-cliapp
  python3-ttystatus ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert ruby-test-unit ruby-xmlrpc ruby2.7-doc rubygems-integration
Veuillez utiliser « sudo apt autoremove » pour les supprimer.
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 7 non mis à jour.
tchoune@tchounePc:~/ruby/myapp$ rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
```